# Can I use 4GB DDR2 sticks in an Acer Aspire 4720 laptop?

Tags: laptop, memory, hardware-rec

I own an Acer Aspire 4720 that has two DDR2 2GB RAM sticks.

Are there any 4GB memory sticks available for this laptop? I would like to expand my RAM from 4GB to 8GB but there are only two slots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Acer site](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/Aspire4720/Aspire4720sp2.shtml) as well as the [Crucial memory configurator](http://www.crucial.com/store/listparts.aspx?model=Aspire%204720&Cat=RAM), the Acer TravelMate 4270 only supports 2GB of non-ECC DDR2 memory per slot.